# How does Bixby retain data from a previous NL input?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I don't understand the way Bixby retains data from previous NL Input. The following example uses the capsule [capsule-sample-shirt](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-shirt).

1. I first use the NL input `find 2 medium shirts` to get a list of shirts.
2. I click on any of those (here i use the *Collar Dress Shirt*), and Bixby asks if I would want to buy it.
3. I click *No* and Bixby informs me with a *Okay, I won't do that*.
4. I now immediately run again the same NL input `find 2 medium shirts` and expect Bixby again to present me with the list of shirts, just like the first time. Instead of the expected list of shirts now, Bixby asks me again *Are you sure you want to buy this?* with the *Collar Dress Shirt* that I previously selected.

**Why is Bixby not showing the list of shirts the second time `find 2 medium shirts` is given as NL input? What would need to happen to make Bixby show the list with this NL input after the first time?**

List of shirts after NL Input:
[image: 1. List of shirts after NL Input]
Bixby waits for confirmation:
[image: 2. Bixby waits for confirmation]
Bixby saying it canceled the prompt:
[image: 3. Bixby saying it canceled the prompt]
Bixby doesn't show the list but instead immediately asks for confirmation:
[image: 4. Bixby doesn't show the list but instead immediately asks for confirmation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the AI part about Bixby.

Each conversation (utterance) without pressing the **reset** key is considered a continuation of last utterance (if any). Thus make the choice of *Collar Dress* and cancel it, but later ask to find 2 medium shirts again, Bixby will try to fill-in the blank with last choice user made.

One clear issue is that now has no way to change the type of shirt unless **reset**, but fix would be easy, make the image of shirt clickable and link actions in view model Confirmation.view.bxb

```
                image-card {
                  aspect-ratio (4:3)
                  image-url ("[#{value(item.shirt.images[0].url)}]")
                  title-area {
                    halign (Start)
                    slot1 {
                      text {
                        value ("")
                        style (Title_M)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  // Add on-click here 
                }
```

You can add on-click similar to change the size and quantity

```
                    input-cell {
                      label ("Quantity")
                      value ("#{value(item.quantity)}")
                      on-click {
                        //This intent relies on searchTerm matching the item which is not a good practice, a better approach
                        //was to allow an ID as input to SelectItem and use `this.id` in the intent
                        intent {
                          goal {
                            UpdateOrder
                            @context (Continuation) { Order }
                          }
                          value { SearchTerm$expr(item.shirt.title) }
                          route { GetQuantity }
                        }
                      }
                    }
```

You may need to add other models to properly promote user.

Hope this will help, and have fun with Bixby!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way for the developer to specify that input should be forgotten? In this case: the user expects to see the list of shirts, so I want to have Bixby not re-use the previous input but instead show the list again. How would I go about to make this happen?